# Sum values from one column if Index column is distinct?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I sum values from one column when index column is distinct?

Initially, I had this SQL query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ISNULL(cast(Quantity as int),0)),0) AS QuantitySum FROM Records
```

Also tried to do this, but this is incorrect when some Quantity values happen to be the same:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(DISTINCT ISNULL(cast(Quantity as int),0)),0) AS QuantitySum FROM Records
```

How can I fix this query to sum only records quantity that is distinct by Index value?

Example of Table:

```
Index    Quantity
AN121    40
AN121    40
BN222    120
BN111    20
BN2333   40
```

So.. I want to return 220

I have duplicate Ids, but quantity can be the same for different records

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you only want to sum one value of `quantity` for each individual value of the index column?

```
select sum(case when row_number() over (partition by `index` order by newid()) = 1
                then cast(Quantity as int)
           end) as QuantitySum
from Records;
```

Or, do you mean that you only want to sum values of `quantity` when there is exactly one row with a given `index` value:

```
select sum(case when count(*) over (partition by `index`) = 1
                then cast(Quantity as int)
           end) as QuantitySum
from Records;
```

Both of these use window functions to restrict the values being processed.

Also, a column called `quantity` should be stored as a numeric type, so conversion isn't needed to take the sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL1
, SUM(COL2)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY COL1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, if you have duplicated Ids and Quantity:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(DISTINCT ISNULL(cast(Quantity as int),0)),0) AS QuantitySum 
FROM (SELECT Id, Min(Quantity) From Records group by Id)
```