# MySQL query: sum column values with distinct for another column

Tags: mysql, join, sum, distinct

I'm trying to build MySQL query with multiple joins whith a sum of joined values. There are 3 tables: custmer, account and deposit. Account and deposit are being joined to customer by their customer_id field. In the end of query all customers are being grouped by their group_id:

```
SELECT customer.*,
COUNT(DISTINCT account.id) as account_count,
SUM(deposit.amount)/(COUNT(deposit.id)/COUNT(DISTINCT deposit.id)) as deposit_sum,
SUM(???) as deposit_first_sum
FROM customer
    LEFT JOIN account ON account.customer_id = customer.id 
    LEFT JOIN deposit ON deposit.customer_id = customer.id 
GROUP BY customer.group_id
```

The problem is: joined rows are duplicated while I've got to make some analytics: summ all deposit amount - you may see my workaround here for deposit_sum. But the real problem is to sum "first deposits made by customers". Before grouping results we may see that there is something like:

```
... deposit.id deposit.customer_id  deposit.amount
...     1               1               10
...     2               1               20
...     3               2               15
...     4               2               30
```

So what I need is to sum only first amount for each customer_id (10 + 15) which would be the "deposit_first_sum".

One limitation here is I'm afraid, I can't use "left join(SELECT ... FROM deposit) as deposit" because it takes a lot of memory while getting all deposit rows from deposit table.

I saw an interesting answer here [Sum values from one column if Index column is distinct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803072/sum-values-from-one-column-if-index-column-is-distinct) 
But it's for MSSQL.

So the question is: is there a way to sum all first deposits without using JOIN(SELECT) or maybe there is a way with JOIN(SELECT) but with some memory economy trick?

UPDATE.
We may also use deposit.account_id which is relation to account table.

Comment: can post the result set of the current query?

Comment: ... deposit records customer_id and not account_id ?

Comment: and will a user have more than one account?

Comment: pala_ Yes we can also join deposits by their account_id and yes user has many accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you the `customer_id` and `amount` for their first deposit, without using a subquery.

```
select d1.customer_id, d1.amount
  from deposit d1
    left join deposit d2
      on d1.customer_id = d2.customer_id and d1.id > d2.id
  where d2.id is null;
```

obviously you can get the `sum` as well:

```
select sum(d1.amount) total_first_deposit
  from deposit d1
    left join deposit d2
      on d1.customer_id = d2.customer_id and d1.id > d2.id
  where d2.id is null;
```

You can also get the total sum, as well as the sum of the first deposits like this:

```
select sum(d3.amount) total_deposit, sum(case when d3.id = d1.id then d3.amount end) total_first_deposit
  from deposit d1
    left join deposit d2
      on d1.customer_id = d2.customer_id and d1.id > d2.id
    inner join deposit d3
      on d1.customer_id = d3.customer_id and d2.id is null
```

Comment: i need to know more about the relationship between the tables before i can include the `account` table in the answer. specifically, if a user can have more than one account. if they can, a deposit should really be recorded against the account, not the customer, otherwise this becomes.. painful

Comment: Thank you! Joining by account_id was the key to this problem.

Comment: ah awesome. yeah it was always going to be hard going from deposit, to customer, to account.